# ImprtError in Django

Tags: django, importerror, manage.py

When I try to run my projects server i get this error:

```
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
import django
File "C:/.../.../.../..../..."
from django.utils.version import get_version
ImportError: No module named utils.version
```

Help, Please.

Comment: I see you're on Windows. Use [virtualenv](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/). It'll make your life so much easier. Using virtualenv is a good practice anyway, but on Windows, doing anything Python related is frustrating without virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a PATH issue. This may happen if you've installed Django as one user and trying to run your django web app as another one. The best way is to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) as xyres mentioned in the comments above.

1. Install virtualenv from `cmd.exe`, run it as an Administrator

   pip install virtualenv
2. Create your own virtual environment

   virtualenv .venv
3. Activate virtual environment on Windows

   .venv/Scripts/activate.bat
4. Or if you're using Linux

   source .venv/bin/activate
5. Now you can install dependencies with pip as a part of your virtual environment

   pip install -r requirements.txt

   pip install django
6. You can exit virtual environment at any moment by typing

   deactivate